# error navigator is not defined in node modules

Tags: next.js

I ran. while using Next.js.

```
npm run dev
(next dev)
```

And get this error.

```
ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
    at getChromeVersion (D:\zummon\page\node_modules\jest-worker\node_modules\supports-color\browser.js:5:68)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\zummon\page\node_modules\jest-worker\node_modules\supports-color\browser.js:14:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1144:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1164:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:993:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1033:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at _supportsColor (D:\zummon\page\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\ChildProcessWorker.js:39:16)
    at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (D:\zummon\page\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\ChildProcessWorker.js:136:24)
```

code in package.json

```
{
 "dependencies": {
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.1",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.3.3",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.4.1",
    "gray-matter": "^4.0.3",
    "next": "^10.2.3",
    "next-mdx-remote": "^3.0.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.11",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.6",
    "postcss": "^8.3.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^4.3.4"
  }
}
```

I also downloaded new version for node.js (v13.6.0) before this happened, if this in case.

I now can't see my editing work, please. I wanna know how to fix this situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the same problem with node.js version 13.6.0. I changed to 14.17.0 and the problem is fixed as well.

Comment: For old window 7 like me using v12.22.1 also work, thank you. I thought it only happens to me